# Does aioredis connection pool context clean up transaction as well?

Tags: python, redis, python-asyncio

```
async def transaction():
    pool = await aioredis.create_pool('redis://localhost')

    with await pool as con:
        await con.execute('multi')
        await con.execute('watch', 'var')
        raise Exception
```

The above transaction is released safely by connection pool context?

---

```
async def transaction():
    pool = await aioredis.create_pool('redis://localhost')

    with await pool as con:
        try:
            await con.execute('multi')
            await con.execute('watch')
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            await con.execute('discard')
```

Otherwise, should I discard the transaction explicitly?